# IIF Expression - Overload resolution failed

Tags: reporting-services

I am getting an the error - "[BC30516] Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'IIf' accepts this number of arguments" when I execute the the below:

```
=iif(Lookup(Fields!OccurCode.Value,Fields!OccurCode.Value,Fields!OccurCode.Value,"TTDC_Papers") <> Fields!OccurCode.Value,"TTDC_Templates", False, True)
```

This to show/hide data based on the above statement. Any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIF takes 3 parameters, but you are passing 4.

You either have to remove the '"TTDC_Templates"' scope reference or, if you have to specify the scope,  use an aggregate function on it with something like `FIRST(Fields!OccurCode.Value, "TTDC_Templates")`